# Turning datagrid values that dont match datasource to datatable

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, datatable

I have a datagrid that gets an extra column with checkboxes added that is not in its source. I am trying to convert the grid that the user sees to a datatable when a save button is clicked. What I am trying to do is run it through a for loop and check if the rows checkbox is checked and the best solution seems to be converting it to a datatable and checking from there.  Most of what I have seen to do the conversion is `Dim dt As DataTable = DirectCast(DirectCast(dtgrd, DataGrid).DataSource, DataTable)` which wont work for me since the checkbox values that I am checking for are not in the datasource. I am trying to avoid a million postbacks so I am not updating anything when the checkbox changes.

Comment: why would you have to cast `DataGrid` to a `DataGrid`? `DirectCast(dtgrd, DataGrid)`

Comment: Was just messing around with what I found online. Was at the point of hitting the keyboard and hoping whatever got typed in worked.

Comment: Your post does not make sense - `the user sees to a datatable` that is what a DataGrid does.

Comment: Then how can I read the html table that it makes back to a datatable?